# ValueError: The number of classes has to be greater than one (python)

Tags: python-2.7, scikit-learn, classification, svm

When passing `x,y` in `fit`, I am getting the following error:

Traceback (most recent call last):

> File "C:/Classify/classifier.py", line 95, in
>
> train_avg, test_avg, cms = train_model(X, y, "ceps", plot=True)
>   File "C:/Classify/classifier.py", line 47, in train_model
>
> clf.fit(X_train, y_train)   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\svm\base.py", line 676, in fit
>   raise ValueError("The number of classes has to be greater than" ValueError: The number of classes has to be greater than one.

Below is my code:

```
def train_model(X, Y, name, plot=False):
"""
    train_model(vector, vector, name[, plot=False])

    Trains and saves model to disk.
"""
labels = np.unique(Y)

cv = ShuffleSplit(n=len(X), n_iter=1, test_size=0.3, indices=True, random_state=0)

train_errors = []
test_errors = []

scores = []
pr_scores = defaultdict(list)
precisions, recalls, thresholds = defaultdict(list), defaultdict(list), defaultdict(list)

roc_scores = defaultdict(list)
tprs = defaultdict(list)
fprs = defaultdict(list)

clfs = []  # for the median

cms = []

for train, test in cv:
    X_train, y_train = X[train], Y[train]
    X_test, y_test = X[test], Y[test]

    clf = LogisticRegression()
    clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
    clfs.append(clf)
```

Comment: scikit learn version 0.15.2

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You probably have only one unique class label in the training set present. As the error messages noted, you need to have at least two unique classes in the dataset. E.g., you can run `np.unique(y)` to see what the unique class labels in your dataset are.

Comment: Just see you already have `labels = np.unique(Y)` in your code example. Just at a `print`, e.g., `labels = np.unique(Y); print(labels)`

Comment: it is printing :

 File "C:/Users/vshah/PycharmProjects/Classify/classifier.py", line 101, in <module>

 Starting classification 

    train_avg, test_avg, cms = train_model(X, y, "ceps", plot=True)


  File "C:/Users/vshah/PycharmProjects/Classify/classifier.py", line 54, in train_model

 Classification running ... 

    clf.fit(X_train, y_train)

  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\svm\base.py", line 665, in fit

[]

    raise ValueError("The number of classes has to be greater than one"

Comment: What you pasted above  is not the print result but the error message that you posted earlier. You need to `print` it in a line before you encounter the error otherwise `print(labels)` will not get executed and you wouldn't now what the variable `labels` contains.

Answer (score 2):

Exactly. your last column (label) has only one type (Classification). you should have at least two. For example; if your label is to decide either you have to offload or not, the label column should have offload  and not-offload or (0 or 1).