# Cannot train new model using Rasa NLU/Sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, rasa-nlu

I am building a middleware between my application and [Rasa NLU](https://github.com/RasaHQ/rasa_nlu) server that can simplify different tasks like creating a model or updating ...

I mainly aim to build a model and update it each time using a function that adds one example to the old model so it just take the old data update it by **adding only one example** and submit it again to Rasa server.

Here's the scenario :
First I start by creating an empty model so I send a post request to `localhost:5000/train?project=defaults&fixed_model_name=model1`
with this data

```
{
  "rasa_nlu_data": {
    "common_examples": [], 
    "entity_synonyms": [], 
    "regex_features": []
  }
}
```

so I get this response :

> "info": "new model trained: model1"

then I start the training with the same request but with new data that contain a new class `greet`

```
{
  "rasa_nlu_data": {
    "common_examples": [
      {
        "text": "hey", 
        "intent": "greet"
      }
    ], 
    "entity_synonyms": [], 
    "regex_features": []
  }
}
```

which works like I expected
and if I add an example from the same class the training always works fine

```
{
  "rasa_nlu_data": {
    "common_examples": [
      {
        "text": "hey", 
        "intent": "greet"
      },{
        "text": "heyy", 
        "intent": "greet"
      }
    ], 
    "entity_synonyms": [], 
    "regex_features": []
  }
}
```

but when I try to post an other data with new different intend `bye` like this

```
{
  "rasa_nlu_data": {
    "common_examples": [
      {
        "text": "hey", 
        "intent": "greet"
      },
       {
        "text": "heyy", 
        "intent": "greet"
      },
      {
        "text": "goodbye", 
        "intent": "bye"
      }
    ], 
    "entity_synonyms": [], 
    "regex_features": []
  }
}
```

I get this error :

> "error": "The number of classes has to be greater than one; got 1"

and also if I redo the same scenario by skipping the second step so my data will look like that:

```
{
  "rasa_nlu_data": {
    "common_examples": [
      {
        "text": "hey", 
        "intent": "greet"
      },
      {
        "text": "goodbye", 
        "intent": "bye"
      }
    ], 
    "entity_synonyms": [], 
    "regex_features": []
  }
}
```

and after submitting it I get this error:

> "error": "n_splits=2 cannot be greater than the number of members in each class."

My Rasa NLU server configuration :

I have already checked those questions that maybe similar to my question but those aren't what I am looking for
[ValueError: The number of classes has to be greater than one (python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40780033/valueerror-the-number-of-classes-has-to-be-greater-than-one-python)

[ValueError: Cannot have number of splits n_splits=3 greater than the number of samples: 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39824600/valueerror-cannot-have-number-of-splits-n-splits-3-greater-than-the-number-of-s)

I know that Rasa model require a number of entities to run the parse but I am far away from that I just want to build  a clean model first

Answer (score 1):

Rasa NLU imposes that you have at least two examples of **each** intent. Though for any kind of good performance you should have much more than that anyway :)