# How to resolve ValueError: The number of classes has to be greater than one; got 1 class

Tags: python, scikit-learn, svm

When I ran the following:

```py
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.2)
clf = SVC(kernel='rbf', probability=True)
clf.fit(x_train, y_train)
```

I received the `ValueError`: `The number of classes has to be greater than one; got 1 class`

I did: `print(np.unique(y_train))`, which returned `[0]`.

Can anyone point me in the right direction for a solution?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40780033/valueerror-the-number-of-classes-has-to-be-greater-than-one-python

Answer (score 1):

Either your `y` list contains no 1's, or the 1's in `y` are few enough that `y_train` may end up containing no 1s. You should print `y`, and in case it contains 1's, you need to change your splitting strategy to ensure that all classes are present in `y_train` and `y_test` at least once

Answer (score 0):

Using `stratify` with `train_test_split` makes this less likely:

```py
train_test_split(X, y, stratify=y)
```

---

**Explanation**: `train_test_split` has randomness. It's possible to produce splits where `y_train` does not contain positive and negative examples, which means we cannot train a discriminative classifier:

```py
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import numpy as np

X = np.ones((8, 2))
y = np.array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1])

_, _, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, random_state=33)
# y_train:   [0 0 0 0 0 0]    # <--- Uh oh, there are no 1s in the training set!
# y_test:    [1 1]
```

*Stratification* first separates data based on the label. This means our training data should have *at least* one of each label:

```py
_, _, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, stratify=y)
# y_train:   [0 0 0 0 1 0]
# y_test:    [0 1]
```